Why Does Firestore's FieldValue.serverTimestamp() Always End with "0000" in Nanoseconds?
Nanosecond Precision:
Does the nanoseconds part of FieldValue.serverTimestamp() always end with "0000"?
Does Firestore provide true nanosecond resolution for server timestamps?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

From the Firebase documentation on data types:

Data type: Date and time
Sort order: Chronological
Description: When stored in Cloud Firestore, precise only to microseconds; any additional precision is rounded down.

So Firestore stores timestamp with microsecond precision, even if the SDKs may expose them with a higher resolution.
